# How to sort files in GNOME Files by Extention or MIME Type?

Tags: gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (Standard) and would like to be able to sort files by their extension or MIME Type so that, for example, different types of images will sort separately.

It looks like this used to be possible in older (Pre-GNOME Files) versions of Nautilus per [this link](https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-sort-files-by-extension-in-ubuntu-nautilus/), but my installation does not offer MIME Type as an option:

[image: No MIME Type]

## How can I enable sorting by MIME Type in GNOME Files 3.36.2 as it ships with Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Your image has `Type` and `Detailed Type`. What do those two do?

Comment: @DKBose that's it exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## MIME Type has been renamed to Detailed Type

Enabling Detailed Type will allow sorting at a more granular level:

[image]

Thank you to @DKBose in the comments for pointing this out.

Comment: Really it is not MIME. The MIME is available in Caja - see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66K8x.png) or output of command like `mimetype /bin/uname`.